# Hessian of a multi-variable function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

I was asked to find the Hessian of the following function:

$$ f(X,Y) = \frac{1}{2}|| M - XY^T||_F^2$$
where $X$ is a $m \times r$ matrix and $Y$ is a $n \times r$ function.

$||z||_F$ is defined for an $ l \times k$ matrix as:

$$ ||z||_F = \sqrt {\sum_{i=1}^l \sum_{j=1}^k Z_{ij}^2}$$

It's a part of an exercise from some course that I haven't covered. I haven't found any resources that helps me to solve this problem. Any help, references will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "$n \times r$ function"? Is $Y$ also a matrix, like $X$? And also what is $M$?